# putting the files in different folders with google app engine... python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, directory

I want to order my python files in different folders, for example : I want to put the main.py and main.html in one main folder.
so may I change the handlers in app.yaml :

```
handlers:
- url: /main.*
  script: main.application
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a script in mainfolder :

```
handlers:
- url: /main.*
  script: mainfolder.main.application
```